# regex to accept optional + in the beginning of mobile number (also accepts only numbers)

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex for mobileNumber `"[1-9][0-9]*"` that accepts only number.
But I need to have an optional + in the beginning. but the user maynot enter + in the beginning.
eg. +9089098909
eg. 9089098909
eg +919089098909
Also I can accept upto 13 characters.
I am working on this.
Can anyone please tell how to fix this?

Comment: Add `\+?` to the beginning of your regex. Note that your current regex doesn't limit the length of the phone number, though.

Comment: Did you try reading some basic regular expression documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specific regular expression in `^\+?\d{,13}$`.  This ensures that you have no more than 13 digits in the number as well as an optional + at the front.

Answer (score 4):

Put `\+?` at the beginning of your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding \\+?[1-9][0-9]* but this is not working

Comment: the `\ `  should be for the `+`. do not double escape.